LM Studio issue in Model Loading
I downloaded the LM Studio version 0.2.18. and downloaded a llm model as shown in the image but it shows "You have 0 models, taking up 0 of disk space." but i have downloaded the model, which is also shown, that's why i am unable to load any of the downloaded llms, and  when i tried changing the default directory it shows the error that is(and this kept on repeating even after selecting any other location or changing it to the default model directory):
Oh snag! There's an issue with your selected models directory.
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setDirPath)
Select option:
Revert to LM Studio Default
Select a Different Folder...
In the image, it shows "You have 0 models, taking up 0 of disk space." but i have downloaded the model, which is also shown, that's why i am unable to load any of the downloaded llms, and  when i tried changing the default directory it shows the error that is shown in the another image  
Error while trying to change the default model directory(because that itself is not working means showing no models, even it contains the downloaded models)
I am expecting to load the locally downloaded model to the lm studio to try them out locally.
